# Swing Java Employee Program

Tags: java, swing

When the user types an employee’s first and last names (separated by a space) in a
JTextField, the employee’s job title is displayed in a secondJTextField. Include
twoJLabels to describe theJTextFields used for data entry, and include a third
JLabel that holds the employee’s title or an error message if no match is found for
the employee

Every thing works fine but when i include following part of code only error message "Employee not found" even if array matches.Without this statement code works fine.please help..thanks

```
 if(!(name.equalsIgnoreCase(empName[x]) ||    job.equalsIgnoreCase(jobName[x])))
    { 
        errorortitle.setText("Employee not found");

    }
```

```
 package appletLesson;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color.*; 
public class JEmployeeTitle extends JApplet implements ActionListener 
{ 
String[] empName = {"James", "Tom", "Steve", "Barack", "John"}; 
String[] jobName = {"Blunt", "Kites", "Jobs", "Obama", "Smith"}; 
String[] jobTitle = {"Actor", "Buisness men", "CEO", "President", "Painter"}; 

JLabel fnameLabel = new JLabel("Enter First Name:"); 
JLabel lnameLabel = new JLabel("ENter Last Name:");
JButton button = new JButton("Submit"); 
JLabel errorortitle = new JLabel(" "); 
JTextField fnameField = new JTextField(20); 
JTextField lnameField = new JTextField(20); 

Container con = getContentPane(); 
public void init() 
{ 
    con.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);    

    con.add(fnameLabel); 


    con.add(fnameField);
    con.add(lnameLabel);
    con.add(lnameField); 
    con.add(button); 
    con.add(errorortitle);
    con.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
    fnameField.addActionListener(this); 
    lnameField.addActionListener(this);
    button.addActionListener(this); 
} 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{ 
    String name = fnameField.getText();
    String job = lnameField.getText(); 
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) 
    { 
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(empName[x]) ||           job.equalsIgnoreCase(jobName[x]))
        { 
            errorortitle.setText(jobTitle[x]);

        } 
        if(!(name.equalsIgnoreCase(empName[x]) ||    job.equalsIgnoreCase(jobName[x])))
        { 
            errorortitle.setText("Employee not found");

        } 
            }
    validate(); 
} 
}
```

Comment: We don't do your homework. What is the error and what have you tried to remedy the situation?

Comment: @hexafraction I'm voting to close...

Comment: How could you tell this was homework?

Comment: @SethCohen - Isn't it obvious?  Even if it is not technically homework, it is some kind of learning exercise.  This is patently not the work of someone trying to write a *real* application.

Comment: heh, yeah i know it is, just trying to be funny

Comment: Stephen is correct..my that part of code is only shows error message "Employee not found"...even if array mathces

Comment: @hexafraction: He said it works unless he includes the bit of code in his snippet, in which case he only sees his "Employee not found" error message.

Comment: Jan Dvorak i have done 98% of code..just stuck in last part and u ruined my question instead of helping me out

Comment: @JamesBlent Don't worry about it being closed, it's fine, you were clear about your question. Does my answer below help?

Comment: @JamesBlent I suggest you read the site's documentation and Java documentation to be familiar with the question process.

Comment: Guys, it's a properly formed question, he just doesn't have the best English. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this loop:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) 
{ 
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(empName[x]) || job.equalsIgnoreCase(jobName[x]))
    { 
        errorortitle.setText(jobTitle[x]);

    } 
    if(!(name.equalsIgnoreCase(empName[x]) || job.equalsIgnoreCase(jobName[x])))
    { 
        errorortitle.setText("Employee not found");

    } 
}
```

You should break out of the loop once you find a match, otherwise you'll just continue through all of the names and overwrite the correct jobTitle with "Employee not found". (I bet your original code works correctly with John Smith and nobody else -- try it.) So, e.g.:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) 
{ 
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(empName[x]) ||           job.equalsIgnoreCase(jobName[x]))
    { 
        errorortitle.setText(jobTitle[x]);
        break; // stop checking
    } 
    if(!(name.equalsIgnoreCase(empName[x]) ||    job.equalsIgnoreCase(jobName[x])))
    { 
        errorortitle.setText("Employee not found");

    } 
}
```

Also I wonder if you mean `&&` instead of `||`, but I don't know exactly what you're going for.

In situations like this it helps to just sit down and look at your code closely. Step through it in your head one line at a time (or use a debugger), and see if you can spot the problem. Write out iterations on paper if it helps.

Hope that helps.

By the way, yes, there are cleaner ways to write the above loops. I'll leave that as an exercise to the OP.